# MassTransit middleware - Getting instance of IServiceProvider

Tags: masstransit, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to create some FluentValidation middleware for my MassTransit pipeline. I thought it would be a suitably easy project for my first ever MassTransit middleware, but I'm afraid I've got in over my head. Can somebody rescue me please?

Other than the [MassTransit middleware documentation](http://masstransit-project.com/advanced/middleware/custom.html) I have been referring to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4Z5puk4jW4) for guidance:

Here's my filter:

```
public class FluentValidationFilter<TMessage> : IFilter<ConsumeContext<TMessage>>
    where TMessage : class
{
    public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
    {
        context.CreateScope(nameof(FluentValidationFilter<TMessage>));
    }


    public async Task Send(
        ConsumeContext<TMessage> context,
        IPipe<ConsumeContext<TMessage>> next)
    {
        var serviceProvider = context.GetPayload<IServiceProvider>();
        // This is always null (I think because I'm using the wrong kind of context).

        var validator = serviceProvider.GetService<IValidator<TMessage>>();

        if (validator is { })
        {
            var message = context.Message;
            var validationResult = await validator.ValidateAsync(message, context.CancellationToken);

            if (validationResult.IsValid)
                await next.Send(context);
            else
                await context.RespondAsync("That one was invalid.");
            // I'm definitely going to have to do something better here, but I'm taking it one step at a time!
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have to observe the configuration of any type of message, and register the filter for that type of message, so for that I made this configuration observer:

```
public class FluentValidationFilterConfigurationObserver : IConsumerConfigurationObserver
{
    private readonly IConsumePipeConfigurator _pipeConfigurator;

    public FluentValidationFilterConfigurationObserver(IConsumePipeConfigurator configurator)
    {
        _pipeConfigurator = configurator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configurator));
    }

    public void ConsumerConfigured<TConsumer>(IConsumerConfigurator<TConsumer> configurator) where TConsumer : class
    {
        return;
    }

    public void ConsumerMessageConfigured<TConsumer, TMessage>(IConsumerMessageConfigurator<TConsumer, TMessage> messageConfigurator)
        where TConsumer : class
        where TMessage : class
    {
        _pipeConfigurator.AddPipeSpecification(
            new FilterPipeSpecification<ConsumeContext<TMessage>>(new FluentValidationFilter<TMessage>()));

        _pipeConfigurator.UseFilter(new FluentValidationFilter<TMessage>());
    }
}
```

Then, in `Startup.ConfigureServices` I execute this extension method to use the configuration observer:

```
public static class FluentValidationExtensions
{
    public static void UseFluentValidation(this IEndpointConfigurator configurator)
    {
        configurator.ConnectConsumerConfigurationObserver(new FluentValidationFilterConfigurationObserver(configurator));
    }
}
```

The `Send` method of my `FluentValidationFilter` never finds an instance of `IServiceProvider` when it calls `context.GetPayload`. I have read that this is because it is not available from `ConsumeContext<TMessage>`, so I tried to implement `IFilter<ConsumerConsumeContext<TMessage>` instead, but that stopped my `ConfigurationObserver` code from compiling because it was no longer of the required type.

I searched for similar-sounding interfaces (like `IConsumerConsumeConfigurationObserver`) and similar sounding overloads (like `ConnectConsumerConsumeConfigurationObserver`) that might have been the correct alternative but I couldn't find anything.

How can I use the right type of context to get the IServiceProvider, but still make use of my `FluentValidationFilterConfigurationObserver`, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Chris Patterson suggestion, you can build a Message Validator Filter:

```cs
public class MessageValidatorFilter<T> : IFilter<ConsumeContext<T>>
    where T : class
{
    private readonly ILogger<MessageValidatorFilter<T>> _logger;
    private readonly IValidator<T> _validator;

    public MessageValidatorFilter(ILogger<MessageValidatorFilter<T>> logger, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _validator = serviceProvider.GetService<IValidator<T>>();
    }

    public async Task Send(ConsumeContext<T> context, IPipe<ConsumeContext<T>> next)
    {
        var validationResult = _validator is not null
            ? await _validator.ValidateAsync(context.Message, context.CancellationToken)
            : new ValidationResult();

        if (validationResult.IsValid is false)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Message validation errors: {Errors}", validationResult.Errors);

            await context.Send(
                destinationAddress: new($"queue:yourcontext-{KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter.Instance.SanitizeName(typeof(T).Name)}-validation-errors"),
                message: new ValidationResultMessage<T>(context.Message, validationResult));

            return;
        }

        await next.Send(context);
    }

    public void Probe(ProbeContext context) { }
}
```

**ValidationResultMessage**:

```cs
public record ValidationResultMessage<TMessage>(TMessage Message, ValidationResult ValidationResult);
```

How to use **ConsumeFilter**:

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(cfg =>
{
    ...

    cfg.UsingRabbitMq((context, bus) =>
    {
        ...

        bus.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(MessageValidatorFilter<>), context);
        bus.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
})
```

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful answer, Antonio. Much appreciated.

Comment: I have just published a Nuget package for FluentValidation with MassTransit built along very similar lines to this accepted answer. It's available here:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidationForMassTransit/

The source code is also available on GitHub here:

https://github.com/BenjaminCharlton/FluentValidationForMassTransit

I'm grateful for the help Chris and Antonio gave me so I hope what I have done helps somebody else in turn.

Answer (score 1):

If you need access to the container from middleware, I'd suggest using a scoped filter. There is [a sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ScopedFilters) that shows how they are built.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Sorry for the delayed "thank you"; I haven't stopped working on this problem and didn't want to report back here until I had made some form of progress.

I thought I was already using a scoped filter because my filter derived from `IFilter<ConsumeContext<TMessage>> where TMessage : class`.

It could be that I was telling the `IConsumePipeConfigurator` to use my scoped filter the wrong way. I was calling `UseFilter` but maybe I should have been calling `UseConsumeFilter` as per these docs.